# Custom wordpress behaviour

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a specific behavior in Wordpress but I fail implementing it.

What I need is that for each blog post permalink that looks like:

```
http://my-website.com/[custom-post-name-here]
```

to have another permalink looking like:

```
http://my-website.com/light/[custom-post-name-here]
```

The second link must use it's own template page, so I can customize the html header section and custom fields differently than in the normal post.

Does anyone have an idea or a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WP create the page with slug `light`.

Set up the `RewriteRule ^light/(.*)$ /light?viewpost=$1 [l]`

Create the `page-light.php` template and load the post there by `$_GET['viewpost']`

Comment: That did the trick. Except that I had to use the `add_rewrite_rule` in my function.php instead in htaccess.
Many thanks Ilya